# Binary search tree with tree traversal

Tags: java, tree, reinventing-the-wheel, binary-search

Although there are several implementations of binary search tree, I have made my own implementation for practice. The following code does the followoing operation
- Create a binary tree
- search through a binary tree
- inorder traversal
- preorder traversal
- breadth first traversal
- depth first traversal(post order)

Please suggest improvements or possible short comming in the code

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Stack;
import org.junit.Test;

public class BST {
public TreeNode root = null;

public TreeNode get(int element){
    if(root == null){
        return null;
    }
    TreeNode runner = root;
    while (true){
        if(runner.data > element){
            if(runner.leftNode == null){
                return null;
            }
            runner = runner.leftNode;
        } else if(runner.data < element) {
            if(runner.rightNode == null){
                return  null;
            }
            runner = runner.rightNode;
        } else {
            return runner;
        }
    }
}

public void insert(int element){
    if(root == null){
        root = new TreeNode(element);
        return;
    }
    TreeNode runner = root;
    while (runner.data != element){
        if(runner.data > element){
            if(runner.leftNode == null){
                runner.leftNode = new TreeNode(element);
                return;
            }
            runner = runner.leftNode;
        } else {
            if(runner.rightNode == null){
                runner.rightNode = new TreeNode(element);
                return;
            }
            runner = runner.rightNode;
        }
    }
}

public static void breathFirstSearch(TreeNode root){
    Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
    queue.add(root);
    TreeNode runner = root;
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
    runner = (TreeNode)queue.remove();
    if(runner.leftNode != null){
        queue.add(runner.leftNode);
    }
    if(runner.rightNode != null){
        queue.add(runner.rightNode);
    }
    System.out.println("visited node " + runner.data);
    }
}

public static void depthFirstSearch(TreeNode root){
    Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<TreeNode>();
    if(root == null){
        return;
    }
    TreeNode runner = null;
    stack.add(root);
    while(!stack.empty()){
        runner = stack.peek();
        if(runner.leftNode != null && !runner.leftNode.visited){
            stack.add(runner.leftNode);
            continue;    
        }
        if(runner.rightNode != null && !runner.rightNode.visited){
            stack.add(runner.rightNode);
            continue;
        }
        stack.pop();
        runner.visited = true;
        System.out.println("visited node " + runner.data);
    }
}

public static void preOrderTraversal(TreeNode root){
    if(root == null){
        return;
    }
    System.out.print(root.data + " ");
    preOrderTraversal(root.leftNode);
    preOrderTraversal(root.rightNode);
}

public static void inOrderTraversal(TreeNode root){
    if(root == null){
        return ;
    }
    inOrderTraversal(root.leftNode);
    System.out.print(root.data + " ");
    inOrderTraversal(root.rightNode);
}

private class TreeNode {
    public int data;
    public TreeNode leftNode;
    public TreeNode rightNode;
    public boolean visited;
    TreeNode(int data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}    



@Test
public void basicTest(){
BST tree = new BST();
int[] data = {9, 5, 3, 1, 4, 8, 15, 11, 21, 20, 29};
for (int i : data){
    tree.insert(i);
}
assertEquals(tree.get(3).data, 3);
}

}
```

Comment: look into this, well explained: http://javabypatel.blogspot.in/2015/08/binary-tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-postorder-levelorder.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Simplify `get`

You can simplify the `get` method like this:

```
public TreeNode get(int element) {
    TreeNode runner = root;
    while (runner != null) {
        if (runner.data > element) {
            runner = runner.leftNode;
        } else if (runner.data < element) {
            runner = runner.rightNode;
        } else {
            return runner;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

*(Thanks [@david-harkness](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/1635/david-harkness) for pointing out the extra shortcut!)*

#### Breadth-first search

It's called breadth-first, not "breath-first".

Also, this initialization is pointless, as you overwrite the value of `runner` immediately in the loop:

> ```
> Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
> queue.add(root);
> TreeNode runner = root;
> while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
>     runner = (TreeNode) queue.remove();
> ```

And, the cast is also pointless, because the `Queue` is correctly declared with `TreeNode` type.

#### Depth-first search

The `depthFirstSearch` method will set all `node.visited = true`, so you won't be able to call it twice. Actually it's really bad to have side effects like this. It would be better if `TreeNode` didn't have the `visited` field at all. It's polluting the class with data only used by one specific purpose, the depth-first search. It doesn't belong there. You could track what was visited using a `Set`, used only in `depthFirstSearch`.

#### `TreeNode`

I would rename `leftNode` to `left` and `rightNode` to `right`. It's simpler and everybody understands what they are.

Since you never need to change `data`, it can be `final`.

The current implementation is limited to `int` values. It would be better if the BST could store anything comparable.

1. Change the class declaration to this:

   ```
   public class BST<T extends Comparable<T>> {
   ```

   Likewise for `TreeNode`
2. Replace all comparison operations like `x.data < value` with `x.compareTo(value) < 0`, likewise for `>`

#### Unit testing

Your basic test could easily become more useful (and less basic) if you do a `get` not only for one random element, but for all elements you inserted, since you have the array of values ready anyway:

```
@Test
public void basicTest() {
    BST tree = new BST();
    int[] data = {9, 5, 3, 1, 4, 8, 15, 11, 21, 20, 29};
    for (int i : data) {
        tree.insert(i);
    }
    for (int i : data) {
        assertEquals(i, tree.get(i).data);
    }
}
```

A single test case named `basicTest` is not going to make this class "properly tested". At the very least you could add a few more test cases that are obviously necessary when talking about a binary search tree.

For example, what happens if you try to get non-existent elements?

```
@Test
public void testNoSuchElement() {
    BST tree = new BST();
    assertNull(tree.get(3));
    assertNull(tree.get(31));
}
```

The BST should not allow duplicate values:

```
@Test
public void testNoDuplicateVaues() {
    BST tree = new BST();
    int val = 3;
    tree.insert(val);
    tree.insert(val);
    tree.insert(val);
    assertEquals(1, tree.size());
}
```

Of course this requires a `.size` method, so implement one, and a test case with it too:

```
public int size() {
    int count = 0;
    Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
    queue.add(root);
    TreeNode runner;
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        runner = queue.remove();
        if (runner != null) {
            ++count;
            queue.add(runner.leftNode);
            queue.add(runner.rightNode);
        }
    }
    return count;
}

@Test
public void testSize() {
    assertEquals(0, new BST().size());
    BST tree = new BST();
    int[] data = {9, 5, 3, 1, 4, 8, 15, 11, 21, 20, 29};
    for (int i : data) {
        tree.insert(i);
    }
    assertEquals(data.length, tree.size());
}
```

#### Formatting

The formatting is messy:

- the indentation is broken in `breathFirstSearch` and in `basicTest`
- you should put a space before and after parentheses, for example:

  - `while(!stack.empty()){` should be formatted as `while (!stack.empty()) {`
  - `if(root == null){` should be formatted as `if (root == null) {`

Basically, use your IDE to format code correctly. It also makes it easier to review. (For yourself too!)

Comment: You could simplify `get` even further with `while (runner != null)` and moving `return null` after the loop. Maybe not simpler per se, but more what I'm used to seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the review, I will incorporate the suggestions

Answer (score 3):

I try not to cover ground already touched upon by @janos's great answer except to emphasize *formatting.* You mostly do a good job with the indentation which is clearly the most important factor, but `breadthFirstSearch` has a `while` loop whose body isn't indented. Consistent spaces around operators (looks like you do), structural parentheses (`if`, `while`, etc), and braces is important, too. As I scan your code, each case of `if(` and `){` sticks out like a sore thumb and distracts.

Naming two traversal methods `Search` is misleading. You aren't searching for a specific value. Use traverse or visit instead.

Why are the traversal methods static?

Tree traversal cries out for recursion! So many of your methods would be simpler using recursion instead of loops, stacks, queues, and visited flags (is that flag even necessary with the looping algorithm?).

```
public static void depthFirstSearch(TreeNode node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }
    depthFirstSearch(node.left);
    depthFirstSearch(node.right);
    System.out.println("visited node " + runner.data);
}
```

Ah, reading further I see you used this for `preOrderTraversal` and `inOrderTraversal`. Why the difference for post-order?

You can also employ recursion in the other methods such as `get` and `insert`. You'll need a helper method to start the recursion, and you can move the recursive methods to `TreeNode` if you like.

```
public TreeNode get(int element) {
    return get(root, element);
}

public TreeNode get(TreeNode node, int element) {
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else if (node.data > element) {
        return get(node.left, element);
    }
    else if (node.data < element) {
        return get(node.right, element);
    }
    else {
        return node;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented some methods using iteration while other using recursion for practicing both approaches. Thanks for the review.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the reviews by @David Harkness and @janos.  I wanted to add a minor point: instead of hard coding your different tree traversal methods to print out the values, you could define those methods to take an argument of type `Consumer<T>` (where `T` is the type that replaces the hard code `int` type).  You can then implement a `Consumer` that just prints out values, but your code could also be used for other things.

Comment: Another option is to implement each traversal method as an iterator.